# should WeakReference<View> be used in RecyclerView.VieweHolder?

Tags: android, weak-references, android-viewholder, android-recyclerview

A simple ViewHolder could be as below.

Should the view element be held in WeakRefererence to avoid strong circular reference with the View this ViewHolder is held?

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mTextContent;
    public ImageView mImageView;

    //or ?
    //WeakReference<TextView> mTextContentRef = null;
    //WeakReference<ImageView> mImageViewRef = null;


    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param v The container view which holds the elements from the row item xml
     */
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        mTextContent = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}
```

Comment: No,  no weak references are required

Comment: Circular references do not stop the objects from being garbage collected.

Comment: @ pskink, could you explain why? it's true it would not stop the GC to collect them, but that may cause the memory free delayed.